# How do I make a button inside a component change the vue router path

Tags: vue.js

I have buttons inside of a component. I am using vue router for vuejs 2.5 and I want to the path to simply change if I click this button. How do I make the path update whenever I click the button.

```js
const Home = { template: '<div>Home <br> <button id="t2">Click Me</button><br><button>go back</button></div>' }
const Foo = { template: '<div>Foo<br this is a page</div>' }
const hello = {
template:'t1',
data(){
return {

}
}
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    { path: '/foo', component: Foo }
  ]
})

new Vue({
 router,
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    msg: 'Hello World'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <router-link to="/">/home</router-link>
  <router-link to="/foo">/foo</router-link>
  <router-view></router-view>
  
  <script type="text/x-template" id="t1">
  <button>hello</button><br> 
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simple add a click listener to the button:

```
 <template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="redirectToHome()">Go Back</button>
    <button @click="redirectToFoo()">Click ME</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

and implement them inside methods

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "#app",
  methods: {
    redirectToHome() {
      this.$router.push({ path: '/' });
    },
    redirectToFoo() {
      this.$router.push({ path: '/foo' });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

For further details on programmatic navigation:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#programmatic-navigation

Comment: Yes. the core features of router.push are available for a while

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "to" prop of vue-route https://router.vuejs.org/api/#to

And on tag prop you must set button value for to render button
https://router.vuejs.org/api/#tag

```
<router-link
    to="/foo"
    tag="button">
        foo
</router-link>
```

Comment: so on my example, I had two buttons. Click ME and Go Back. How do I make these go to Foo. Would router link be nested inside of the component or it must stay where it is?

Comment: Must stay there. If you want nested, you must put <router-view> inside other <router-view>